Decrement value MongoDB, prevent negative number
I'm using MongoDB and I have a document where I want to increment a count field. However, I need to ensure that this count does not go below zero. For example, if inc is -2 and the current count is 1, applying $inc will result in -1, which I want to avoid.
Here's the current update operation I'm using:
db.collection.updateMany(
  { '_id': {'$in': object_ids} },
  { 
    '$inc': { 'count': inc },
    '$addToSet': {...},
    '$set': {...},
  }
)

I've tried these 2 , but as '$addToSet' can not be added as a pipeline stage I can not use sth like this:
db.collection.updateMany({ '_id': {'$in': object_ids} }, [ { $set: { count: { $cond: { if: { $gte: [{ $add: ['$count', inc] }, 0] }, then: { $add: ['$count', inc] }, else: 0 } } } } ] )

I also thought of using
'$expr': { '$gte': ['$count', 0] }

but this doesn't prevent decrementing to negative!

Can you provide sample document? From your query, I don't see the scenario that decrementing to negative. Demo

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"... but as '$addToSet' can not be added as a pipeline stage " You can try using the $concatArrays aggregation operator or even the $reduce. Both operators are used on array types.

One possible solution is to use a two-step process:

use updateMany with $inc to increment the count fields of the documents.
db.collection.updateMany(
        { '_id': { '$in': object_ids } },
        { 
          '$inc': { 'count': inc },
          '$addToSet': {...},
          '$set': {...},
        }
      )


use another updateMany operation with $max to set any negative count fields to zero.
db.collection.updateMany(
    { '_id': { '$in': object_ids }, 'count': { '$lt': 0 } },
    { 
      '$set': { 'count': 0 }
    }
  )



Note: this is not an atomic operation, you might need to use a transaction

If you put both operations and the check inside a pipeline, it would be atomic.

Please see if the below query useful, it uses $add and $expr
// the value to update
const updateval = -1;
    
db.test.updateMany({$expr:{$gte:[{ $add:[updateval, "$a"] },0]}},{$inc:{a:updateval}});

A test case
// a test document
db.test.find();
[ { a: 1 } ]
    
// the value to update
const updateval = -1; 

// updating 
db.test.updateMany({$expr:{$gte:[{ $add:[updateval, "$a"] },0]}}, 
{$inc:{a:updateval}});
    
// the value has changed, it is now zero
db.test.find();
[ { a: 0 } ]
    
// updating again 
db.test.updateMany({$expr:{$gte:[{ $add:[updateval, "$a"] },0]}}, 
{$inc:{a:updateval}});

// value did not change since it goes below zero
db.test.find();
[ { a: 0 } ]


Thanks! I think this could work, but not with the always true, if: { $eq:[1,1]}. How would you check 'if': { '$gte':['$_count'-inc,0] ?

Thank you for your feedback. You can give me some test documents and values which you may find to confirm.

Please be informed, today, the post has been revised and removed the $cond operator. Now it in query just adds and checks if the new value greater or equal to 0. If yes, it updates, otherwise there is no update.

Is the issue still persisting ?

It is possible to complete all operations in one shot with aggregation in an update pipeline.

$inc: chain up $add result with $max with 0 to bound it to zero if it is negative
$addToSet: put them in a $setUnion to perform the same behaviour
$set: just put the other entries in the $set stage

db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      count: {
        $max: [
          0,
          {
            $add: [
              "$count",
              -2// increment
              
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      arr: {
        "$setUnion": [
          "$arr",
          // your input in $addToSet
          [
            "AAA",
            "BBB",
            "CCC"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})

Mongo Playground
